# iOS 8 - Alterando manualmente permissões do Core Location

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para iOS 8 e requisito a permissão para `CLLocationManager`, porém se o usuário não aceitar a permissão e tentar alterar nas configurações de privacidade, as configurações fecham no momento da seleção (semelhante a um Crash) e ao retornar no painel de configurações, o mesmo ainda está selecionado a opção "Nunca".

Problema: Por mais que o usuário tente alterar esta permissão ele nunca irá conseguir. Isso acontece com o aplicativo em background ou totalmente inativo.

Comment: Deixa eu entender. Você está dizendo que dá *crash* quando você tenta alterar as configurações do seu aplicativo em *Ajustes > Privacidade > Serviço de Localização* do próprio sistema iOS?

Comment: Na verdade em: Ajustes > aplicativo em questão > Localização

Comment: crie um projeto simples reproduzindo o problema e compartilhe para que eu possa analizar pois parece ser erro de lógica